# Check Appointment Response Status

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

Looping over a series of appointments in an Outlook Calendar from Excel. Each Appointment is sent to two people - the organiser and attendee.

The email to the attendee is sent in the format employeeid@contoso.com but on the recipient list employee.name@contoso.com is automatically added and it is this recipient name that the response status  is recorded against.

How to check this response status which is recorded against the users email address (fullname@contoso.com) - but the invite is sent to the alias (employeeid@contoso.com) - it is only the employee id that I have to check against.

The loop so far executes over the calendar appointments for a given employee id, checks the subject of the appointment contains the employee id and checks it is in the future.

```
For Each oObject In oFolder.Items
    If oObject.Class = olAppointment.Item Then
        Set oMeetingItem = oObject
        If InStr(oMeetingItem.Subject, EmpID) And _
            (oMeetingItem.Start > Date() ) And _ 
            ( insert check on employee.name@contoso.com > )
            ' Do something
```

Is this extra recipient added because employeeid@contoso.com is an alias?

**UPDATE**

I have checked the ResponseStatus of several appointments. They all evaluate to 1 - olResponseOrganized - even the appointments where the attendee has declined.

I can check each attendee's response status with:

```
            ' LOOP OVER ATTENDEES AND IF DECLINED THEN DELETE FROM CALENDAR
        Set objAttendees = oMeetingItem.Recipients
        For Each objAttendee In objAttendees
            If objAttendee.MeetingResponseStatus = olResponseDeclined Then
                oMeetingItem.Delete
                ' other statements
            End If
        Next
```

Is there a more elecgant way to check if the employee@contoso.com has declined.

Comment: Something like `olResponseStatus` ? [link to MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.olresponsestatus)

Comment: @ProfoundlyOblivious the question is if it is possible and how to get employeename@contoso.com from employeeid@contoso.com

Comment: Ok. Yes it is possible and the link I provided well help.  The other question you asked isn't very clear because you use inconsistent terminology without sufficient code to see the context.  I can suggest looping through the `Recipients` property of either the `MeetingItem` or the `MailItem`.  I suspect you are populating the wrong field instead of properly using `Resolve`.

Comment: @ProfoundlyOblivious Thanks. Can you explain the reference to resolve? I do not see it mentioned in the link you posted.

Comment: `Resolve` resolves the email address :)  It tries to validate the email address string by using the address book.  If you've ever seen an email where one recipient has a line under the name and the other is just plain text, the resolved recipient has the line.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [AppointmentItem.ResponseStatus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.appointmentitem.responsestatus) property which returns an `OlResponseStatus` constant indicating the overall status of the meeting for the current user for the appointment.

Also, instead of iterating over all items in the folder and getting them according to the condition defined (subject and start date):

```
For Each oObject In oFolder.Items
```

You need to use the `Find`/`FindNext` or `Restrict` methods of the `Items` class. The Find method locates and returns an Outlook item that specifies the provided filter. It accepts a string value reflecting the criteria that a result item should meet. The format of the string depends on the field type that you are going to filter by. Please note that there are some item properties that you can’t use for the filter. You can read more about the properties not allowed in the filter string and string formats used for the search criterion on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869662.aspx).

Read more about these methods in the following articles:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)

You may also find the `AdvancedSearch` method of the `Application` class which provides the following benefits in Outlook:

- The search is performed in another thread. You don’t need to run another thread manually since the `AdvancedSearch` method runs it automatically in the background.
- Possibility to search for any item types: mail, appointment, calendar, notes etc. in any location, i.e. beyond the scope of a certain folder. The `Restrict` and `Find`/`FindNext` methods can be applied to a particular `Items` collection (see the `Items` property of the `Folder` class in Outlook).
- Full support for DASL queries (custom properties can be used for searching too). You can read more about this in the [Filtering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208216%28v=office.12%29) article in MSDN. To improve the search performance, Instant Search keywords can be used if Instant Search is enabled for the store (see the `IsInstantSearchEnabled` property of the Store class).
- You can stop the search process at any moment using the `Stop` method of the `Search` class.

Comment: Nice response.  Will give +1 if edited to solve the OP's email address problem.

Answer (score 0):

I can not find a way to obtain the primary smtp address from the alias that the invite is sent to, to check the response status.

In lieu, this function will check an appointment and loop over the recipients returning True if anyone has declined:

```
Function CheckForDeclines(oMeetingItem As Object) As Boolean
Dim objAttendee As Recipient
Dim objAttendees As Recipients

Set objAttendees = oMeetingItem.Recipients

For Each objAttendee In objAttendees
    If objAttendee.MeetingResponseStatus = olResponseDeclined Then
        CheckForDeclines = True
        End Function
    End If
Next objAttendee
End Function
```

As per the previous answer a better way to get a list of items is using [Restrict](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.restrict):

```
Dim restrictedItems As Outlook.Items
Dim dateRestrictedItems As Outlook.Items
Dim finalRestrictedItems As Outlook.Items
Dim oMeetingItem As Outlook.AppointmentItem
Set ns = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set nsOther = ns.CreateRecipient("user@constoso.com")

Set oFolder = ns.GetFolderFromID("000000004BE5311AB6885142BD830C7FA8991BF601004167A737474922409B71F960AFD45A65")

Set restrictedItems = oFolder.Items

' Construct filter for items in the future
tdyDate = Format(Date, "Short Date")
strRestriction = "[Start] >= '" & tdyDate & "'"
Set dateRestrictedItems = oFolder.Items.Restrict(strRestriction)

' Construct a filter for subjects that contain ”test”.
Const PropTag  As String = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/"
strRestriction = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) & PropTag _
& "0x0037001E" & Chr(34) & " like '%test%'"

Set finalRestrictedItems = dateRestrictedItems.Restrict(strRestriction)

For Each oApt In finalRestrictedItems
     Debug.Print (oApt.Subject & " " & oApt.Start)
     Debug.Print (oApt.ResponseStatus)
Next
```